# TRIGGER: Read NEW.values and OLD.values during "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, on-duplicate-key

I'm trying to write a mini-auditing system for individual tables in MySQL.

I had good luck working with basic `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` commands, however now a table I'm interested in auditing uses `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

By using a trigger `ON BEFORE INSERT` I can tell this event is occurring, however I can only get half the data I'm interested in.  `NEW.values` are readily available, but I've no idea how to get the `OLD.values` that came before.  I suppose I could do a query using the `NEW.ID` in existing table, but I'm not sure about performance and reliability.

I need the `OLD.values` because I'm storing both old and new values for each change event since I read somewhere that was a good idea for collapsing data etc...

Is there a way in MySQL 5.0 (or newer GA release) to reliably retrieve these values as though I were in an `UPDATE` trigger?

EDIT: Another wrinkle:

Looks like the `NEW.values` do not match the data after update.  They match the `INSERT` statement not the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` data that will actually go into the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the trigger event `ON AFTER UPDATE` *also* catches the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` change.  From here, I was able to get OLD/NEW values and perform the logging I needed to perform.